# How do i set width to Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, width, cell

I want to set the width of custom UITableViewCell to 80% of the screen width but I know the size of the cell can be manipulated using "layoutSubviews()" methods but I don't know how.

Please help me.

Comment: you can take view in custom cell that fill 80 % , and set content view color = clear color

Comment: You can do it in the story board . instead of telling atleast write the code what you tried.

Comment: You cant tell us to write a code for you you have to give some code snippet if any errors there then we can help. Please check How to Ask Question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @user5744323 Override var frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag and drop `UIView` to your `content view` of `cell` (i.e. in cell). Adjust it's height and width according to your need as you said 80% (so give padding like wise). The set `top,bottom,leading and trailing` constraints if you are using autolayout.

You can set your contentview's background color as clear color and cell's background as clear color as well or desired color you want. Likewise you can set your tableview's background color also!

Answer (score 14):

The answer is too simple. Just change the frame of the cell in class.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {


    override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set (newFrame) {
            var frame = newFrame
            let newWidth = frame.width * 0.80 // get 80% width here
            let space = (frame.width - newWidth) / 2
            frame.size.width = newWidth
            frame.origin.x += space

            super.frame = frame

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
class CustomTVC: UITableViewCell {

    override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set (newFrame) {
            var frame = newFrame
            frame.size.width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width * 0.8
            super.frame = frame
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One new available solution is to use the "inset grouped" style which Swift now offers for UITableViews. This creates an appearance with more narrow UITableViewCells like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SLfF.png)